# Which piece of code initialize 'Event Source'?

Tags: java

I understand that 'Event source' (For example Button) generates Event Object which is then processed by Listener. My Question is which code actually initialize 'Event Source' to generate Event. When i click a button is it JVM that initialize Button class or Operating System... or something else?

Comment: Which _Button_ are you referring to? [AWT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html) or [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) or something else? Perhaps [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) ?

Comment: @Abra, My question is in contrext of AWT

Comment: @Abra , Also after going through your 'AWT' link i found mentioned "When a button is pressed and released, AWT sends an instance of ActionEvent to the button". Then Again my question would be who triggers AWT to send instance of ActionEvent to the button.

Comment: Who triggers AWT? The OS. Who triggers the OS? The hardware. Who triggers the hardware? You. In the end it all boils down to _you_ pressing that button :)

Comment: The wonderful thing about the JDK is you have access to all the source code. Class `AWTEvent` has a constructor that has an `Object` parameter which is the _source_ of the event. Most modern IDE's can search for the code that invokes `AWTEvent` constructor. Good luck!